# Cannot access superuser in Django admin page created by python manage.py createsuperuser

Tags: django

When I create the superuser in Django, which runs successfully, when I try to enter in the admin path in my browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/ and insert the email and the password, I get the following error:

**Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.**

Can you help me? I don't understand where is the problem.

I have defined the following fields in the Account models.py file:

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Are you using a custom User model?

Comment: Yes, I have included other fields as well, which I need. It is a bit strange, because before it worked, but after I made some changes to my code, I deleted the db.sqlite3 file and the migration files to start everything from the beginning to have a clear environment, and now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Can you share the custom model and your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting?

Comment: Sure: AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_backend.Account'; then the Account class has the flags I wrote above except of other fields, like the email etc

Comment: You run python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate?

Comment: Yes, obviously, otherwise, I would get an error. The superuser is create successfully. But when I go to the admin page it shows me the error, as if the user I created was not a superuser

Comment: My intuition says it should be something with the setting file, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Found what was the problem: I was supposed to set user.is_active = True.  I had forgotten to insert this